# How to convert a message's value from hexadecimal to decimal?

Tags: capl, canoe

I need to write a function that converts a message's byte (this.byte(2)) from hexadecimal to decimal, from a message I receive on the CAN bus.
For example i have the following message on the CAN bus "F1 02 1A 13 00 00 00 00" The function should then returns the value 26 for this.byte(2) "1A".

I followed some examples found on the internet but I still don't get the right value.
What is then wrong with my function ?

```
variables
{
  char hexa[2];
  long decimal, place;
  int val, len;
}

int HexToDec(char hexa[])
{   
  decimal = 0;
  i=0;
  place = 1;

  len = strlen(hexa);
  len--;

  for(i=0; hexa[i]!='\0'; i++)
  {
 
      if(hexa[i]>='0' && hexa[i]<='9')
      {
          val = hexa[i] - 48;
      }
      else if(hexa[i]>='a' && hexa[i]<='f')
      {
          val = hexa[i] - 97 + 10;
      }
        else if(hexa[i]>='A' && hexa[i]<='F')
        {
            val = hexa[i] - 65 + 10;
        }

        decimal += val * _pow(16, len);
        len--;
    }

    write("Hexadecimal number = %s\n", hexa);
    write("Decimal number = %lld", decimal);

    return 0;
}

on message *
{
  HexToDec(this.BYTE(2));  // for example 1A in hexadecimal
}
```

Comment: What is the content of your variable `hexa`? Is it a hexadecimal character? E.g. `F` which should be converted to `15`? Or is it a _raw_ value, e.g `0x0F` which should be converted to `15`?

Comment: @M.Spiller The content should be the "this.byte(x)" i am trying to convert. I am not sure what does CANoe returns back as a variable, but I thought maybe it returns 0F that's why i wrote hex[2] and obviously it is wrong that's why i am asking here.
When i use ``write(" Byte : %x ", this.byte(2));` I obtain for example "0F".

Comment: Can't you just assign it to the long variable? Like `decimal = this.byte(2)`

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement "convert hex to decimal" is a wrong statement. Because both Hexadecimal and Decimal are numbers. Your function `HexToDec` is taking string as input and not a number.
If you want to print `this.BYTE(2)` as a decimal value, you just have to write

```
write("Hex - %X", this.BYTE(2));
write("Dec - %d", this.BYTE(2));
```

Comment: I don't want to write it as decimal. I need to use the number for further work.

Comment: Then, you can simply use `this.BYTE(2)` for further calculations if you are using it in the same event. Or if you want to save it, you can use
`int ByteValue;
ByteValue = this.BYTE(2)`